# How to lazy load image in MUI Avatar?

Tags: material-ui

How to lazy load images in MUI `Autocomplete` rendering of `Avatar` images?
Given a Autocomplete component with 500+ items and each item includes an image rendered using Avatar component. I see that on user tapping into Autocomplete textfield, all 500+ items are being rendered and trying to load all images unnecessarily. I tried using imgProps property to Avatar component but it had no effect.

```
imgProps={{ loading: "lazy" }}
```

Is there an option to delay image loading until the user scrolls through the list and the component is visible to user?